# add Filter method to Service Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to filter my json so that it doesn't display empty tables. I have a filter method that I'm trying to add to my service but I can't. If anyone has a solution, I'd appreciate it.

thank you everyone.

**json**

```
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
  emptyArray: [], // hide this element from my service
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
}
```

**service**

```
result!:string;

private firstPartUrl = 'whatever url 1';
private secondPartUrl = 'whatever url 2';

constructor(http:HttpClient) {}

get(bigramme:string): Observable<Interface> {
 this.result = brigramme;
 return this.http.get<Interface>(this.firstPartUrl+bigramme+secondPartUrl).
  pipe(
    filter(key => this.result[key].length > 0));
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Do you want to remove emptyArray from JSON if emptyArray length is 0 ?

Comment: yes this code works in my components.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
return this.http.get<IResponse>(`${ this.firstPartUrl }${ bigramme }${ secondPartUrl }`)
  .pipe(
    map((obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (!obj[key].length) {
          delete obj[key];
        }
      });
      
      return obj;
    }),
  )
```

Another tip: don't set interface names as "Interface" (**ISomething** or **SomethingInterface** will be much better), and don't set methods as "get" or "set" (**getSomething** or **setSomething** will be better too).